# How to determine the width of a grid-item when its width is auto and grid-container has justify-items set to something other than stretch

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to workout how to determine the width of a grid-item when the grid-item's `width: auto` and `justify-items` is a value other than `stretch`.

In the example below I've noticed a few things.

I am looking at the first grid-item coloured red.

I am looking at its width.

When `justify-items: start|end|center`...

It seems that if you add 30px of either horizontal padding, border or margin (pbm) the content-area of the grid-item shrinks and the item's inline-dimension (padding, border, margin) stays within its cell.

However, it seems to be when pbm is 32px that the content-area stops shrinking and you can see the item's inline-dimension creep over its grid-cell. Why is this?

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;
  grid-template-rows: 300px;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  font-size: 19px;
  justify-items: start;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-container> :nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.grid-container> :nth-child(2) {
  background-color: orchid;
}

.grid-container> :nth-child(3) {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteturadipisicing elit. t incidunt facilis rem doloribus. ng elit. t incidunt facilis rem doloribus.
  </div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. t incidunt facilis rem doloribus.
  </div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. t incidunt facilis rem doloribus.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `justify-items: stretch` the grid items *can* shrink to fit their column.

From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#justify-self-property):

> The `stretch` keyword can cause elements to shrink, to fit their container.

---

And keep in mind that each columns has a fixed width of 200px.

```
.grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;
}
```

---

With other values for `justify-items`, such as `start` and `center`, the grid item can exceed the column width based on content, padding, borders and margins.

In the case of the first column in the question, the source of the problem is a long string of text:

```
"consecteturadipisicing"
```

Break that up and the problem is resolved for all practical purposes.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;
  grid-template-rows: 300px;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  font-size: 19px;
  justify-items: start;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-container> :nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.grid-container> :nth-child(2) {
  background-color: orchid;
}

.grid-container> :nth-child(3) {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet con sec tetura dipi sicing elit. t incidunt facilis rem doloribus. ng elit. t incidunt facilis rem doloribus.
  </div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. t incidunt facilis rem doloribus.
  </div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. t incidunt facilis rem doloribus.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 'With other values for justify-items, such as start and center, the grid item can exceed the column width based on content, padding, borders and margins.' I am already aware of this. In my example, when horizontal padding, border or margin (pbm) grows from 0px to 30px, the content-area shrinks (because `width: auto`). All of a sudden, at 32px, content-area stops shrinking and pbm is added externally. Why is this?

Comment: @tonitone106 it stops shrinking because the width reaches the minimum width on the content. The minimum width is the width of the longest word `consecteturadipisicing`

Comment: Thanks @ZohirSalak. May I ask how you discovered this answer? Perhaps W3C documentation or MDN?

Comment: @tonitone106 It is basically the definition of `min-content`  https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#min-content Read the **Note** below the definition to have a more general understanding of what's going on